# How to convert object type values to float type in pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

How to convert all values of a `pandas` dataframe to `float` data *type* unless they are non-numerical strings (i.e., are combination of digits and non-digit characters). In other words, I want to convert `object` type to `float` type while leaving everything else untouched.

Comment: Note that this is not a good idea, mixed types are not efficient.